# Cloudwatch Metric Filter for Json

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to create cloudwatch alarm from RDS events to get notified on instance events such as availability, failure. Created log group for RDS instance events. Now I have to create metric filter from the JSON. However, the json filter pattern doesn't work. I am trying the example given by aws. The test pattern does not show any results matching to the json. Pls help me.

**Sample JSON from AWS :**

```
{
  "eventType": "UpdateTrail",
  "sourceIPAddress": "111.111.111.111",
  "arrayKey": [
        "value",
        "another value"
  ],
  "objectList": [
       {
         "name": "a",
         "id": 1
       },
       {
         "name": "b",
         "id": 2
       }
  ],
  "SomeObject": null,
  "ThisFlag": true
}
```

**Metric Filter Query:**

```
{ $.eventType = "UpdateTrail" }
```

**Result Screenshot:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Removed the line break and it worked in the test pattern.